# itemize and rename items within tcolorbox

Tags: itemize, tcolorbox

In reference to a [similar post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304713/itemize-inside-tcolorbox/351231?noredirect=1#comment862875_351231), I am trying to replace the numbering of `\item` with a bracketed word. However, if the renamed bullet is long enough, it ends up out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}
     \item[{[blablababakbakbakb]}] \lipsum[1]
     \item[{[blubllanlanlanlan]}] \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea of how to get around this?

Comment: You are using the wrong list. Use description instead of itemize.

Comment: This is no `tcolorbox` problem. Without the `tcolorbox` around the itemize, the leakage of the labels into margin would even be larger

Comment: thanks, but `\description` compiles the list similarly to what is proposed in the answer below. What I wanted, if possible, is to have something like above, but _inside_ the box.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize list dimensions with `enumitem` package, in your case just increase `itemindent` and add `align=left` to align label with left side

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}[itemindent=2.5cm,labelsep=4mm,labelwidth=3cm,align=left]
     \item[{[blablababakbakbakb]}] \lipsum[1]
     \item[{[blubllanlanlanlan]}] \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

If you need all text to be indented you can just  increase `leftmargin`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3.2cm]
     \item[{[blablababakbakbakb]}] \lipsum[1]
     \item[{[blubllanlanlanlan]}] \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! this sounds good, although I was thinking about something slightly different. What I wanted, if possible, is to have the entire text of a bullet completely indented and the bullet _inside_ the box. Does that make sense?